# ReactJS component to classify a list of books

Tags: javascript, react.js

In my project, I am getting an array of objects from api, and I want to divide the array into 3 three arrays based on the value of the `shelf` property of each
array element which is an object. Now for doing that I am using `formatBooks` function inside the same component.

Later on I am passing this `formatBooks` function as prop to other component which calls this function.

I was hoping if there is any better by making another component and place the formatBooks inside that. I wanted to know a better and elegant way of doing things like this.

```
class BooksApp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    books: [],
    searchResults: [],
    newBooksFromSearch: [],
  }
  //format the books array
  formatBooks = () => {
    const currentlyReading = []
    const read = []
    const wantToRead = []
    this.state.books.forEach( item => {
      if(item.shelf === "currentlyReading" || item.shelf === "Currently Reading"){
          item.setShelf = "Currently Reading"
          currentlyReading.push(item)
      } 
      if(item.shelf === "read" || item.shelf === "Read" ){
          item.setShelf = "Read"
          read.push(item)
      }    
      if(item.shelf === "wantToRead" || item.shelf === "Want to Read"){
          item.setShelf = "Want to Read"
          wantToRead.push(item) 
      } 
    })
    return(
      {
        currentlyReading: currentlyReading,
        read: read,
        wantToRead: wantToRead
      }
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may start to make your code slightly less verbose (and with all the required semicolons):

```
const result = {
    currentlyReading: [],
    read: [],
    wantToRead: []
};

this.state.books.forEach(item => {
    if (...) {
        item.setShelf = "Currently Reading";
        result.currentlyReading.push(item);
    }
});

return result;
```

---

Then you might simplify comparison using regular expressions:

```
if (item.shelf.match(/^currently\s?reading$/i)) { ... }
```

---

Now you can see that you are MUTATING THE STATE without using `setState()`. That's an Incredibly Bad Thing™. You do not give enough context to provide a specific suggestion then I'll mention few:

1) Do not mutate existing objects, create new ones:

```
if (item.shelf.match(/^currently\s?reading$/i) {
    result.currentlyReading.push({ ...item, setShelf: "Currently Reading" });
}
```

2) Perform this *translation* in `componentDidUpdate()` when you populate the `books` state property.

3) If you're using Redux then perform this translation in your Reducer (or Selector, if you're using them).

---

Re-think your design. Why do you need to **duplicate** an information you already have? What do you need these lists (with slightly changed values) for if they're already there in `state.books`? Let's imagine an hypothetical `render()` method:

```
render() {
    const { books } = this.state;

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Shelf title="Currently reading" books={books} filter="^currently\\s?reading$" />
            <Shelf title="Read" books={books} filter="^read$" />
            <Shelf title="Want to read" books={books} filter="^want\\s?to\\s?read$" />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Your separate lists are now *obsolete*. If you do not care about localization then regex for `filter` attribute might even be calculated directly (inside `Shelf` component!) with something like:

```
const filter = new RegExp(`^${this.props.title.replace(" ", "\\s?")}$`, "i");
```

Even if I am not doing this in my example please note that regular expression text MUST be escaped (before calling `.replace()`): [Escape string for use in Javascript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3446170/1207195).

---

Now that you have a separate component...you may consider to move selection again outside and use memoization, simplified example (pseudo-code for memoization, pick the package you prefer):

```
render() {
    const { books } = this.state;

    const read = memoize((list, filter) => list.filter(book => book.shelf.match(filter)));

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Shelf title="Currently reading" books={read(books, /^read$/i)} />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Note that I'm NOT using the `setShelf` property any more in favor of `Shelf.title` property.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a more elegant way.
I recommend creating a new utility module to hold your formatBooks function.  Import the module into any component that needs it.

A good approach is:

1. Create very simple Controls.
2. Create the data you wish you had to keep your control simple.
3. Test your control, with that data.
4. Select/transform your data from the data you have to the data you want.
5. Finally use your transformed data

**1. Create very simple Controls.**

```js
const Book = props => (<li>{props.title}</li>)
const Header = props => (<li className='header'>{props.shelfTitle}</li>)
const Group = props => {
    const {shelfTitle, books} = props;
    const booksMap = title => (<Book title={title}/>)
    const booksList = books.map(booksMap)
    //prefer <React.Fragment> over <div>
    return (
        <div>
            <Header shelfTitle={shelfTitle}/>
            {booksList}
        </div>)
}
const GroupList = props => {
    const groupMap = d => (<Group  shelfTitle={d.shelfTitle} books={d.books}/>)
    const booksList = props.bookData.map(groupMap)
    return (<ul>
        {booksList}
    </ul>)
}
```

**2. Create the data you wish you had to keep your control simple.**

```js
const groupedBooksData = [
    {shelfTitle:"Read", books: ["Deep Work"]},
    {shelfTitle: "Want To Read", books:["Antifragile", "MindSet"]}
]
```

**3. Test your control, with that data.**

```js
const groupedBooksData = [
    {shelfTitle:"Read", books: ["Deep Work"]},
    {shelfTitle: "Want To Read", books:["Antifragile", "MindSet"]}
]
const Book = props => (<li>{props.title}</li>)
const Header = props => (<li className='header'>{props.shelfTitle}</li>)
const Group = props => {
    const {shelfTitle, books} = props;
    const booksMap = title => (<Book title={title}/>)
    const booksList = books.map(booksMap)
    //prefer <React.Fragment> 
    return (
        <div>
            <Header shelfTitle={shelfTitle}/>
            {booksList}
        </div>)
}
const GroupList = props => {
    const groupMap = d => (<Group  shelfTitle={d.shelfTitle} books={d.books}/>)
    const booksList = props.bookData.map(groupMap)
    return (<ul>
        {booksList}
    </ul>)
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
<GroupList bookData={groupedBooksData} />,
document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.header {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

li {
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

**4. Select/transform your data from the data you have to the data you want.** 
Often data you get from an api isn't in the form/shape you want.  This is a good time to practice TDD.  Avoid forEach in favor of map, reduce, filter and sort.

```js
//data you have
const books = [  
    { title: "Deep Work", shelf: "read" },
    { title: "Antifragile", shelf: "wantToRead"  },
    { title: "Mindset", shelf: "wantToRead" },  
    { title: "How to Win Friends and Influence People", shelf: "currentlyReading"  },
    { title: "The Power of Habit", shelf: "read"  },    
    { title: "Fooled By Randomness", shelf: "listenTo" }
]

const reduceToLists = (accumulator, item, i) => { 
    const oldTable = accumulator[item.shelf] || []
    oldTable.push(item.title)
    accumulator[item.shelf] = oldTable
    console.log(i, item, accumulator)
    return accumulator; 
}
const formatBooks = list => list.reduce(reduceToLists, {})
const result = formatBooks(books)
// reduceToLists is called books.length times and 
// has a console.log(
//i              item                                accumulator)
//0 {title: "Deep Work", shelf: "read"}         {read: [Deep Work]}
//1 {title: "Antifragile", shelf: "wantToRead"} {read: [Deep Work], wantToRead: [Antifragile]}
//2 {title: "Mindset", shelf: "wantToRead"}     {read: [Deep Work], wantToRead: [Antifragile, Mindset]}
//.....

console.log("Data you want", result);
```

Prefer pure functions and immutable data.  This function is equivalent to reduceToLists but is pure and immutable.

```js
//Data you have
const books = [  
    { title: "Deep Work", shelf: "read" },
    { title: "Antifragile", shelf: "wantToRead"  },
    { title: "Mindset", shelf: "wantToRead" },  
    { title: "How to Win Friends and Influence People", shelf: "currentlyReading"  },
    { title: "The Power of Habit", shelf: "read"  },
    { title: "Clean Code", shelf: "read"  },
    { title: "Fooled By Randomness", shelf: "listenTo" },
    { title: "Purple Cow", shelf: "read"  },
    
]

const reduceToLists = (accumulator, item, i) => { 
    const oldTable = accumulator[item.shelf] || []
    oldTable.push(item.title)
    accumulator[item.shelf] = oldTable
    console.log(i, item, accumulator)
    return accumulator; 
}
const formatBooks = list => list.reduce(reduceToLists, {})


const titleCaseMap = {
    wantToRead: "Want To Read",
    read: "Read",
    currentlyReading: "Currently Reading",
    listenTo: "Listen To"
}// actually would use: https://github.com/blakeembrey/change-case 


//use formatBooks
const transformListOfBooks = books => {
    const booksObj = formatBooks(books); //{read: [Deep Work, ...], wantToRead: [Antifragile, Mindset, ...]}
    const keys = Object.keys(booksObj); //[read, wantToRead, currentlyReading, ...]
    const mapToTitle = (key, i) => { 
        const result = {
            title: titleCaseMap[key],
            list: booksObj[key]
        };
        console.log(i, key, result)
        return result;
    }
    //without console.log above can be simplified to 
    //const mapToTitle = key => ({title: titleCaseMap[key], list: booksObj[key]}) 
    return keys.map(mapToTitle)  
}

console.log("Data you want", transformListOfBooks(books))
```

**5.  Finally use selected data**

```js
//Data you have
const books = [  
    { title: "Deep Work", shelf: "read" },
    { title: "Antifragile", shelf: "wantToRead"  },
    { title: "Mindset", shelf: "wantToRead" },  
    { title: "How to Win Friends and Influence People", shelf: "currentlyReading"  },
    { title: "The Power of Habit", shelf: "read"  },
    { title: "Clean Code", shelf: "read"  },
    { title: "Fooled By Randomness", shelf: "listenTo" },
    { title: "Purple Cow", shelf: "read"  },
    
]

const reduceToLists = (accumulator, item, i) => { 
    const oldTable = accumulator[item.shelf] || []
    oldTable.push(item.title)
    accumulator[item.shelf] = oldTable
    console.log(i, item, accumulator)
    return accumulator; 
}
const formatBooks = list => list.reduce(reduceToLists, {})


const titleCaseMap = {
    wantToRead: "Want To Read",
    read: "Read",
    currentlyReading: "Currently Reading",
    listenTo: "Listen To"
}// actually would use: https://github.com/blakeembrey/change-case 


//use formatBooks
const transformListOfBooks = books => {
    const booksObj = formatBooks(books); //{read: [Deep Work, ...], wantToRead: [Antifragile, Mindset, ...]}
    const keys = Object.keys(booksObj); //[read, wantToRead, currentlyReading, ...]
    const mapToTitle = key => ({shelfTitle: titleCaseMap[key], books: booksObj[key]}) 
    return keys.map(mapToTitle)  
}



const Book = props => (<li>{props.title}</li>)
const Header = props => (<li className='header'>{props.shelfTitle}</li>)
const Group = props => {
    const {shelfTitle, books} = props;
    const booksMap = title => (<Book title={title}/>)
    const booksList = books.map(booksMap)
    //prefer <React.Fragment> 
    return (
        <div>
            <Header shelfTitle={shelfTitle}/>
            {booksList}
        </div>)
}
const GroupList = props => {
    const groupMap = d => (<Group  shelfTitle={d.shelfTitle} books={d.books}/>)
    const booksList = props.bookData.map(groupMap)
    return (<ul>
        {booksList}
    </ul>)
}
const dataYouWant= transformListOfBooks(books);
// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
<GroupList bookData={dataYouWant} />,
document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.header {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

li {
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```